# What is this GNUstep folder?

Tags: files, directory

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I opened the GUI and noticed this folder called GNUstep and Mail. Here is a screenshot of it:[image]

Inside GNUstep is Library which is empty. And inside of Mail is Drafts and Outbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First its GNUstep not GNUsetup , some one downloaded or installed it on your desktop .

GNUstep provides an environment to easily develop advanced GUI desktop applications as well as server applications.

GNUstep offers Development tools for command-line and GUI development, as well as the foundations for a Desktop environment, which other projects can complete.

[Reference](http://www.gnustep.org/)

Comment: I dont like unused files on my GUI. Can I delete it?

Comment: if you don't work with it , just delete it .